# Springboot RabbitListener rollback after queue TTL

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-transactions, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Is there some way to rollback a transaction executed into a RabbitListener event? I have something like below

```
@Autowired private SomeService service;

@RabbitListener(queues = {"some-queue-ttl-5s"})
@Transactional
public SomeOutputMessage handleMessageQueue(SomeInputMessage inputMessage){
    //do something
    return service.processInput(inputMessage); //JPA update transaction
}
```

I tried using Transactional but even after the message gets expired `x-message-ttl` the `processInput` will commit the transaction. I wonder if we can rollback the process and send the inputMessage to a DLX.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking; if the listener throws an exception the message will be requeued and redelivered (by default). Message expiration has nothing to do with the listener code; that's for expiring messages that aren't delivered.

Comment: My problem is that I have an async producer that will publish to a queue and wait like 5s, after this timeout the Listener shouldn't process the message and let it goes to DLX. So I wonder I can rollback the transaction after TTL in Listener

Comment: It's still not clear; the TTL only applies if the message sits in the queue for that time. If it's already been sent to a consumer, you are out of luck, You could configure only one message being sent to the consumer at a time, by setting the `prefetchCount` to 1.

Comment: Got it. I understand this is not a rabbitmq issue, but maybe SpringBoot has some mechanism to handle it, actually, that is the question. If somehow I can tell spring-boot to not process messages that would reach timeout on the producer's side.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Spring Boot; TTL is handled by the broker before the message is sent to a consumer. All you can do is minimize the outstanding messages at each consumer by reducing the prefetch (to 1 at the most extreme). The whole point of messaging is to decouple the producer and consumer. You could have the producer add a header containing a timestamp `dontProcessAfter`, but the clocks on the producer and consumer would need to be synchronized; you can then discard expired messages in the consuming application.